# How to prove surjection

Tags: functions, special-functions

> Determine if function $f(x)=\frac{1-2x}{x-2}$ is invertible. If it is,
>   show the inverse function.

I need help with proving surjectivity of the function.

The domain is $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{2\}$, since $x-2 \neq 0 \implies x \neq 2$.

Range is $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{-2\}$, because of:

$
y=\frac{1-2x}{x-2}\\
yx-2y=1-2x\\
yx+2x=1+2y\\
x(y+2)=1+2y\\
x=\frac{1+2y}{y+2}\implies y \neq -2
$

$f:\mathbb{R} \setminus \{2\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \setminus \{-2\}$

How can I prove a surjection?

Comment: Well, you've done it.  for any value $y\neq -2$ you showed that $f\left(\frac {1+2y}{y+2}\right)=y$, thus we can get every value except for $-2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you mean injectivity because you have shown surjectivity?

Since if you fix any $y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \left\{2\right\}$, then for $x \ne 2$:
$$y=\frac{1-2x}{x-2}\iff x=\frac{1+2y}{y+2}$$

The function is also injective because $f(a)=f(b)$ implies $a=b$; since for $a \ne 2$ and $b \ne 2$:
$$\begin{align}\frac{1-2a}{a-2}=\frac{1-2b}{b-2} & \iff (1-2a)(b-2)=(1-2b)(a-2) \\
 & \iff b-2-2ab+4a = a-2-2ab+4b \\
& \iff b+4a=a+4b\\
& \iff a=b\end{align}$$

Comment: I meant surjectivity, because I just didn't know I showed it, when I checked domain and range.

I proved injectivity doing this:
Suppose $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{2\}$ and $x_1\neq x_2$

$f(x_1)-f(x_2)=\frac{1-2x_1}{x_1-2}-\frac{1-2x_2}{x_2-2}=\frac{(1-2x_1)(x_2-2)-(1-2x_2)(x_1-2)}{(x_1-2)(x_2-2)}=\frac{(x_2-2-2x_1x_2+4x_1)-(x_1-2-2x_1x_2+4x_2)}{(x_1-2)(x_2-2)}=\frac{x_2-2-2x_1x_2+4x_1-x_1+2+2x_1x_2-4x_2}{(x_1-2)(x_2-2)}=\frac{3x_1-3x_2}{(x_1-2)(x_2-2)}=\frac{3(x_1-x_2)}{(x_1-2)(x_2-2)}\neq0
$